# C# - Display an Image on right side of MenuItem

Tags: c#, winforms

I am having a MenuItem with the text `Chart Type`. In that, I have sub MenuItems. Now, In a MenuItem with text `A`, I want an image to the right.

There should be two different click behaviors, One on clicking of MenuItem and one for clicking on the image at right. But I am unable to get the image there. What I have tried it -

```
    mnItem = new MenuItem("A", new EventHandler(A_Clicked));
    mnItem.OwnerDraw = true;            
    mnItem.DrawItem += mnItem_DrawItem;
    mnItemContainer.MenuItems.Add(mnItem);

    void mnItem_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {        
        System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(MainForm));
        Image zeroIconBmp = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("cmdSearch.Image")));
        double factor = (double)e.Bounds.Height / zeroIconBmp.Height;
        var rect = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y,
                             (int)(zeroIconBmp.Width * factor),
                             (int)(zeroIconBmp.Height * factor));
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(zeroIconBmp, rect);
    }
```

> I am bound to use MenuItem.

[image]

Comment: Why do you need it on the right ? It breakes the default pattern....

Comment: On left, I have tick mark. Means the selected MenuItem will be ticked with a right symbol (✔).

Comment: @FelixD. It would be okay if I can get image even on left.

Answer (score 2):

The default way would be like this:

All you need to do is to set the `Image` propertie of your `MenuItem`.

**Note that this is `ToolstripMenuItem` not `MenuItem`.**

Via `Designer`:

[image]

Via `Code`:

[image]

Result: [image]

Comment: I am unable to get property 'Image' in MenuItem.

Comment: I use `ToolStripMenuItem`. `MenuItem` has no such property.

Comment: Yup, I  need to search some other work around. Will try `ToolStripMenuItem` if it fits in my design.

Comment: Why are u bound to use `MenuItem` ?

Comment: Its a part of already written code. Adding Image is new requirement. So If I use ToolSripMenuItem then have to change whole old code.

Comment: I can understand that.. But still I'm not sure if it's better to do alot of extra work (reinventing the wheel) when something is already possible with an existing control. Up to you !